# wanderlust: hook for modifying buffer *WL:Message* as it is being accessed

Tags: message, wanderlust

I want to optionally perform some functions on the data in buffer `*WL:Message*` right after I access and view it.

For example, when first viewing a new message in the `*WL:Message*` buffer via `wl-summary-read` or `wl-summary-enter-handler`, I'd like to perform the following logic (pseudo-code) ...

```
Enter the *WL:Message* buffer
IF *WL:Message* buffer contains images
THEN
   Scroll down to the first image
   Do a (recenter 1) to position this image at the top of the window
ENDIF
```

I know how to write the elisp code to do all of this. The problem is knowing ***when*** to issue this code. I haven't been able to find a hook that runs right as the `*WL:Message*` buffer is being displayed.

I tried to use advice around various existing wanderlust `wl-summary` and `wl-message` functions, but I haven't found a reliable way to do what I want. Sometimes (seemingly at random), the `wl-message-buffer` variable is not set, or that buffer's window is not live (it needs to be a live window in order for **`(recenter 1)`** to work).

Does anyone know of the proper place I can insert my code so that it always reliably runs whenever I first view a new message in the `*WL:Message*` buffer?

Comment: NOTE to the person who edited my message. This is the wanderlust `*WL:Message*` buffer, not the emacs `*Messages*` buffer. I changed this to be precise ...

Comment: How about using the `wl-message-display-internal-hook`?  There are too many possibilities that I am not fully aware of that may affect displaying a buffer, so I cannot duplicate your own settings to test it out.  The hook is on almost the last line of `wl-message-display-internal` (which gets called near the end of `wl-message-buffer-display`), so it looks promising.  I disabled default displaying of buffers in Wanderlust and almost everything is `noselect` (i.e., populated in the background) so that I can display the WL folders and buffers wherever and whenever I choose.

Comment: I see that `wl-summary-down` may also be getting in your way, so you may wish to have a look at that too.  Functions like that are what I have removed in my custom version ...  See also `wl-message-redisplay-hook`.

Comment: It turns out that `wl-message-redisplay-hook` will indeed work for me. See my answer, below, for details. I can accept my answer in 22 hours from now, and I then will do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help from *lawlist*, I figured out the solution.

I'm pretty sure I had tried `wl-message-redisplay-hook`, but I was incorrectly trying to use the variable `wl-message-buffer` to get the current `*WL:Message*` buffer. However, in that hook (and in many other places in the wanderlust code), that variable's value is set to `nil`. In general, I believe we cannot ever reliably use the `wl-message-buffer` variable.

However, in `wl-message-redisplay-hook`, the `(current-buffer)` function will correctly return a reference to a live `*WL:Message*` buffer instance containing the new message. I can then do whatever I want within that buffer.

Here's my code for performing the function I described above ...

```
(defun my-redisplay-func ()
  ;; As long as this function is run as a
  ;; wl-message-redisplay-hook, (current-buffer)
  ;; will return an instance of a live *WL:Message*
  ;; buffer.
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window (current-buffer))))
    (when win
      (with-selected-window win
        (let ((cur (point-min))
              (end (point-max))
              (image-pos))
          ;; Get the position of the first displayed
          ;; image, if there is one.
          (while (and (not image-pos) (<= cur end))
            (when (get-char-property cur 'display)
              (setq image-pos cur))
            (setq cur (1+ cur)))
          (when image-pos
            ;; Scroll to the first image row and reposition
            ;; it to the bottom of the window.
            (goto-char image-pos)
            (next-line)
            (recenter -1)
            (goto-char image-pos)))))))
(add-hook 'wl-message-redisplay-hook 'my-redisplay-func)
```